tkinter: prevent horizontal mouse wheel (on trackpad) from influencing vertical scroll
I am customizing a VerticalScrolledFrame borrowed here.
It is actually a frame that contains a scrollbar and a canvas in which there is another frame.
The canvas is able to scroll with the scrollbar, but I want the <MouseWheel> event  to provoke vertical scroll.
I added this in the __init__ method of the class VerticalScrolledFrame:
class VerticalScrolledFrame(ttk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, master, *args, **kw):
      ...

      match sys.platform:
         case "win32": mwspeed = lambda n: -n/120
         case "linux": mwspeed = lambda n: -n/120
         case "darwin": mwspeed = lambda n: -n

      def _on_mousewheel(event):
         canvas.yview_scroll(mwspeed(event.delta), "units")
      
      canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

This works. Unfortunately, it works too well: when I scroll horizontally, I expect it to do nothing but it also scrolls vertically.
The problem is that it seems a bit odd on my Mac, especially when I scroll up when it's already at the top of the frame: imperceptible horizontal movements cause vertical vibrations on the frame.
Am I misusing the <MouseWheel> event? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

You need to separately catch horizontal scrolling events, and ignore them (or at least do something other than vertically scrolling your Canvas in response to them).  Apparently this can be done via a binding on <Shift-MouseWheel>.

You can also detect if the shift is pressed (for horizontal movement) using shift_pressed = event.state&1

@jasonharper Thanks !
canvas.bind_all("<Shift-MouseWheel>", lambda e: None)
works exactly as expected, even if I don't understand why the <Shift-MouseWheel> was included in the <MouseWheel> event before.
